# Can my libspotify operate offline?

Tags: spotify

I have a Windows .Net application integrated successfully with libspotify.dll (Version 11). I would like it to operate in offline mode, i.e. when login responds with UnableToContactServer? If this is possible (Premium Account) how is it best done?

Comment: Further to this question. Spotify API is clearly attempting an offline login as its issuing a log message to that effect:LogMessage: 13:12:20.253 I [c:/BuildAgent/work/2195a75f132bb24/client/core/session/offline_authorizer.cpp:297] Unable to login offline: no such user

Comment: I am not sure why this is failing other than the usual device/account/facebook username-password problem.

Comment: Have you tried again with version 12?